# One domain for multiple hosting server

Tags: domain, hosting, saas

Please help me to setup architecture one saas / multi tenant application.

I have one domain for example example.com on server 1
I am providing one one billing software in sub domain of example.com.
For this i have created a wild card sub domain. and developed the software such way each domain will open respective customer billing software login screen.

Now the scenario is, what if i want to attach a new server, how can i create new sub domain on example.com for new client?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution: Put up a  reverse proxy in front of your servers that forwards to the correct one.